# How to change the windows 10 wallpaper with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am looking to change the Windows desktop background wallpaper in C++ using the Windows API.

I have read the following posts on this topic:

- [How to change desktop background using VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886948/how-to-change-desktop-background-using-vc)
- [SystemParametersInfo sets wallpaper completly black (using SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710677/systemparametersinfo-sets-wallpaper-completly-black-using-spi-setdeskwallpaper)

**Problem:**

When I execute the code, the desktop background changes to completely black like in the post above (yes, I did try the suggested fix in that post. No luck.)

**Code:**

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    std::string s = "C:\\picture.jpg";
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (PVOID*)s.c_str(), SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
    return 0;
}
```

I have also tried just `(void*)` instead of `(PVOID*)` above and an `L` in front of the string. Nothing works so far.

**SOLVED:**

Changing `SystemParametersInfo` to `SystemParametersInfoA` (as suggested in the comment and answer) did the trick.

Comment: Check the return and use [`GetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror). Also, are you compiling for Unicode?

Comment: Use SystemParametersInfoA() to ensure it is compatible with std::string

Comment: I agree that it's most likely a wide vs narrow char issue - `SystemParametersInfo()` info is a macro for either SystemParametersInfoA or SystemParametersInfoW depending on the unicode #define. You could make it windows style explicitly by doing `const wchar_t * s = L"C:\Picture.jpg";` and calling it with SystemParametersInfoW (or visa-versa with `const char` and SystemParametersA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you should use a `wchar_t` as input for `SystemParametersInfo()` instead of a string and also use `SystemParametersInfoW()`.

The following code worked for me:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    const wchar_t *path = L"C:\\image.png";
    int result;
    result = SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void *)path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
    std::cout << result;        
    return 0;
}
```

Where `SystemParametersInfoW()` should return true if it manages to change the background. I print it out as `result` for clarity when running the application.

Comment: if you use SystemParametersInfoA() then u can pass a string