# SystemParametersInfo sets background to solid color rather than actually setting the picture

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10

**I have tried all of the solution specified on these posts:**

1. [How to change the windows 10 wallpaper with C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549147/how-to-change-the-windows-10-wallpaper-with-c)
2. [How to change desktop background using VC++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886948/how-to-change-desktop-background-using-vc)
3. [SystemParametersInfo sets wallpaper completly black (using SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710677/systemparametersinfo-sets-wallpaper-completly-black-using-spi-setdeskwallpaper)

And i **still** cant seem to be able to get it working.... heres my code:

```
const wchar_t* path = L"C:\\imagge.png";
bool result = SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, (void*)path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
std::cout << result;
```

Also if i specify a path that aint valid it still prints 1(true) when it clearly states on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER bit that it should return 0(false) if theirs a problem

Also i have tried calling printing out `GetLastError();` and it returns 0....

> Note  When the SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER flag is used, SystemParametersInfo
>   returns TRUE unless there is an error (like when the specified file
>   doesn't exist).

Comment: Have you tried using [IDesktopWallpaper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper) instead?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use a png here. Use a bmp file.

Comment: thank you @IInspectable that interface is much easier and works!

Comment: To set a solid color you remove the wallpaper, you don't set it to a image with a single color. Make it match COLOR_DESKTOP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IInspectable suggested using [IDesktopWallpaper interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idesktopwallpaper)

And i got it working!

Heres my code:

```
int main() {
std::wstring x = L"C:\\Users\\danie\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\pixelArt\\Sample.png";
HRESULT  ad;
CoInitialize(NULL);

IDesktopWallpaper* p;
if(SUCCEEDED(CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DesktopWallpaper), 0, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, __uuidof(IDesktopWallpaper), (void**)&p))) {
    ad = p->SetWallpaper(NULL, x.c_str());
    p->Release();
}

CoUninitialize();
return 0;
}
```